# Using multiple UNION

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following query where I want to select **one** result from 4 tables based on

`datum` DESC. It works when I'm using for only one WHERE clause and it works.
Working following query:

```
(SELECT 'naruceno' ai, dimnjacar, datum_unosa as datum from naruceno 
    WHERE dimnjacar = 1 UNION SELECT 'odradeno'  ai, dimnjacar, datum from odradeno
    WHERE dimnjacar = 1 UNION SELECT 'odbijanja' ai, dimnjacar, datum from odbijanja
    WHERE dimnjacar = 1 UNION SELECT 'obavijesti'  ai, dimnjacar, datum from obavijesti
    WHERE dimnjacar = 1 ORDER BY `datum`  DESC LIMIT 1)
```

I'm trying to make something like this with another WHERE clause:

```
(SELECT 'naruceno' ai, dimnjacar, datum_unosa as datum from naruceno 
    WHERE dimnjacar = 1 UNION SELECT 'odradeno'  ai, dimnjacar, datum from odradeno
    WHERE dimnjacar = 1 UNION SELECT 'odbijanja' ai, dimnjacar, datum from odbijanja
    WHERE dimnjacar = 1 UNION SELECT 'obavijesti'  ai, dimnjacar, datum from obavijesti
    WHERE dimnjacar = 1 ORDER BY `datum`  DESC LIMIT 1) UNION
    (SELECT 'naruceno' ai, dimnjacar, datum_unosa as datum from naruceno 
    WHERE dimnjacar = 2 UNION SELECT 'odradeno'  ai, dimnjacar, datum from odradeno
    WHERE dimnjacar = 2 UNION SELECT 'odbijanja' ai, dimnjacar, datum from odbijanja
    WHERE dimnjacar = 2 UNION SELECT 'obavijesti'  ai, dimnjacar, datum from obavijesti
    WHERE dimnjacar = 2 ORDER BY `datum`  DESC LIMIT 1)
```

But it doesn't work. 
Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Can you show sample data and expected results? Also, define `But it doesn't work`. What are you getting for results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could be both the query result the same result so try using UNION ALL

```
select * from 
(    SELECT 'naruceno' ai, dimnjacar, datum_unosa as datum 
    from naruceno 
    WHERE dimnjacar = 1 UNION 
    SELECT 'odradeno', dimnjacar, datum 
    from odradeno 
    WHERE dimnjacar = 1 UNION 
    SELECT 'odbijanja', dimnjacar, datum 
    from odbijanja
    WHERE dimnjacar = 1 UNION 
    SELECT 'obavijesti', dimnjacar, datum 
    from obavijesti
    WHERE dimnjacar = 1 
    ORDER BY `datum`  DESC LIMIT 1)  t1
UNION ALL  
select * from 
(
    SELECT 'naruceno' ai, dimnjacar, datum_unosa as datum 
    from naruceno 
    WHERE dimnjacar = 2 UNION 
    SELECT 'odradeno'  ai, dimnjacar, datum 
    from odradeno
    WHERE dimnjacar = 2 UNION 
    SELECT 'odbijanja' ai, dimnjacar, datum 
    from odbijanja
    WHERE dimnjacar = 2 UNION 
    SELECT 'obavijesti'  ai, dimnjacar, datum 
    from obavijesti
    WHERE dimnjacar = 2 
    ORDER BY `datum`  DESC LIMIT 1)   t2
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION SELECT 'odradeno'  ai, dimnjacar, datum from odradeno
    WHERE dimnjacar' at line 2

Comment: answer  updated .. but are you sure the column datum exists in the (and is not named  always  datum_unosa ??'

Comment: That's it  :D Thank you !